# live Webcam streaming to adobe media server from a website

Tags: adobe, media, live, webcam

I am trying to make a website which will have this option to stream live from the logged in person's account. I mean that if a person wants to broadcast from his webcam, he ll just click on a button on the web page and streaming to the adobe media server will start. Is there a way to do this?